# roman numerals and regex

Tags: java, regex

I am working on a program that determines is a entered string is a roman numeral. my issue is that in the following code

```
    public void romancheck(String num){
    if(num.isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No number typed");
    }
    if (num.matches("[IVXLCDM]+")){
        repeatefinder(num);
       if(repeated == 'I' || repeated == 'V' || repeated == 'X' || repeated == 'L' || repeated == 'C' || repeated == 'D' || repeated == 'M'){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, repeated + " is repeated more than three times in " + num);
       }
       else{
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, num + " is a roman number"); 
       }
    }
    if(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  + " is not a roman number in " + num);
}
}
```

I use the regex `num.matches("[IVXLCDM]+")` to determine if the entered string only contains roman numeral chars my issue is i want to print a message if a char in the string is not a roman numeral char using the last if statement. what would be the most effective way to find the chars in the string that are not roman numeral chars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This finds the first occurance

```
else {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[^IVXLCDM]").matcher();
    matcher.find();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, matcher.group() + " is not a roman number in " + num);
}
```

This finds all occurances

```
else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, num.replaceAll("[^IVXLCDM]", "") + " are not roman numbers in " + num);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `replaceAll` with your regex on the input string, so that only characters that are *not* roman numerals are left over, with underscores between to preserve the index:

```
String notRomanNumerals = num.replaceAll("[IVXLCDM]+", "_"); 
System.out.println("Error: not all characters are roman numerals: "+  notRomanNumerals);
```

If then you want the index of the character in the string, then just do

```
for(int i=0;i<notRomanNumerals.length;i++) {
    if(notRomanNumerals.charAt(i) != '_') {
        // i is an index of a char that is not a roman numeral
        // Do what you want with it
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but your "show index of" code won't handle multiple occurrences of the same invalid character

Comment: Yep, just realized that, updated to give the index os all invalid characters